# postgres dropdb with commands in terminal

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

With Postgres you can add a new database with the following command on Ubuntu:
`sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/createdb --echo --owner=root foobar`
But how can I remove that database? `sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/dropdb --echo --owner=root foobar` doesn't work, but the dropdb does exists in /usr/bin.

Comment: dropdb does not have or need an --owner option.

Answer (score 0):

To drop a PostgreSQL database using the `dropdb` executable use:

```
dropdb -h host -p port -U username dbname
```

Then fill in the password of `username`.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not it: 
```sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/dropdb -h localhost -p 5432  -U root foobar;                                                                                                     !607
sudo: unknown user: postgres```
same for ```sudo /usr/bin/dropdb -h localhost -p 5432  -U root foobar```, then it asks for password, I filled in the password I use everywhere for Postgres, but it isn't recognized.

Comment: If the linux user postgres does not exist, then `sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/createdb --echo --owner=root foobar` would not have worked, either.  Are you logged onto the computer you think you are?